# Initialize configuration in application factory on flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, factory

I saw some sample codes, but I can't understand some part of these codes.

Here is the content of sample codes:

- Flask application structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
└── config.py
```

- config.py:

```
    import os
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    
    class Config:
        SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'hard to guess string'
        # ...
        
            @staticmethod
        def init_app(app):
            pass
    
    
    class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
        # ...
    
    
    class TestingConfig(Config):
        # ...
    
    
    class ProductionConfig(Config):
        # ...
    
    
    config = {
        'development': DevelopmentConfig,
        'testing': TestingConfig,
        'production': ProductionConfig,
        'default': DevelopmentConfig
    }
```

- app/**init**.py

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from config import config
    # ...
    
    def create_app(config_name):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
        config[config_name].init_app(app)
            # ...
        return app
```

I want to know the usage of these lines:

- `config[config_name].init_app(app)`
- ```
  def init_app(app):
      pass
  ```

If I ignore it, what would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flask, init_app is the common method to combine the FlaskApp and the third-libs

If you don't want to do something, don't define the `init_app` method